# Faraday's law - direction of non-conservative electric field

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

I would like to conduct the following experiment. I place charged particle above the wire and increase current in the wire. I expect particle to move, but not sure of the direction of the movement. Here is my illustration [image: illustration].

Applying Faraday's law over the first circle I can guess direction of the electric field. I indicated it with arrow next to word EMF. Similarly applying Faraday's law over the second circle, I am guessing direction of electric field with arrow. As you can see those two arrows are in the opposite direction. Where would point A move? Did I guess incorrectly direction of non-conservative electric fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faradays law works for any loop, I can make any shape I want.

When I apply faradays law, does this mean the electric field is in the same direction of the loop $(\vec{dl})$ at every point on the loop I choose?

No.

Faradays law says nothing about direction. Just the total emf. Meaning the actual value and direction of the electric field is uniquely determined by the arrangement of the charges causing the field.

The key question is:

Is there an actual conducting wire there?

If the answer is no, then the above explanation suffices.

If there IS an actual conducting wire, more care must be taken, to ensure that the charges that make up your wire are taken into account when finding the direction of the field.

Macroscopically the wire is neutral, yet in reality, there are surface charges that arrange themselfs to make the E field follow the wire, and to also make the field constant.

Much like in any regular wire, due to the E field from a battery.

The emf assuming there is a wire, vs isn't. Is the same, but the direction of E along the loop I choose is different.

Comment: Thank you so much! Without conductive wire force points in the direction of current, but with wire it creates current that moves to oppose change in flux. This is quite unique force, since if we replace it with ordinary electric field, we will no get current in the wire at all. This is puzzling. Is there an explanation to it?

Comment: The presence of the wire changes the direction. And not sure what you mean I that last part. But I think you are distinguishing an E field with curl, and an E field without

Comment: I am trying to get more detailed microscoping understanding how presence of wire changes direction? Is it possible to illustrate it with just two charges (-/+, they are neutral on macro scale) and induced force. 
I am not sure I understand what E field with and without curl is? It looks like E field curls only when there is a wire.

Comment: Just because there is curl in an E field doesn't mean the field litterally has to curl, ie in a circle pattern. Most of the Time it does, but not always. Curl just is a property of a vector field, and certain curl elements like the B field of a straight wire can add up to form straight lines. The closed line integral is still non zero. $  \nabla × \vec{E} = -\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}$ When there is a changing B field there is curl

Comment: The presence of surface charges has absolutely nothing to do with the curl of the E field. Stationary surface charges in the wire have no curl, and thus doesn't effect the curl of the E field at a point. They do however make the E field  look  more "curly", by the introduction of an arrangement of divergence of the E field

Comment: Remember the E field further away from the wire is weaker than near, despite being in straight lines. This field has the same mathematical "curl" of the E field despite looking less "curly" than the field with an actual conductive loop. This more "curly" looking field, looks the way it does, as a result of its divergence due to surface charges

Comment: Thank you again! I guess I found answer to my question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69000/direction-of-the-induced-electric-field
 It looks like we cannot distil induced electric field, we can only talk about changes in the fields. Anyway it would be interesting to see how change in magnetic flux affects individual charges. It is probably area of research.

Comment: So when we have single charge, I am expecting it to move against current, since it needs to generate flux in opposite to the one produced by main current. What happens when we have two charges (+ and -) liks hydrogen atom?